# Unable to cut wide banner image fully using selenium webdriver only some part of image is cut

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, screenshot

I am trying to cut wide banner image from web page which is in iframe using selenium webdriver java, but i am able to get only partial banner image after cutting using below code.

I have tried below code wghich is giving me only partial banner image.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//amp- 
 img[@class='img_ad 
 i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-element 
 i-amphtml-layout']//img[@class='i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml- 
 replaced-content']"));
 File screen = ((TakesScreenshot) 
 driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
 Point point = element.getLocation();
 int xcordinate = point.getX();
 int ycordinate = point.getY();
 int imageWidth = element.getSize().getWidth();
 int imageHeight = element.getSize().getHeight();
 BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(screen);
 BufferedImage destination = img.getSubimage(xcordinate, ycordinate, 
 imageWidth, imageHeight);
 ImageIO.write(destination, "png", screen);
 File screenshotLocation = new 
 File("C:\\shots\\screenshotOfElement.png");
 FileUtils.copyFile(screen,screenshotLocation);
```

Please let me know what changes i should do in my code to get the complete banner image after cutting using above code.

Comment: Please post page source code (or URL).